# How to Temporarily Remove the Last Commit with Git?

Tags: git, version-control, revert

Suppose I have the following git commits:

1. `aaaaaa`
2. `bbbbbb`
3. `cccccc` (the latest)

I would like to go back to `bbbbbb` and continue the development from there. Essentially, I want to remove `cccccc` *for now* and be able to retrieve it in the future (I know I'd still need the `cccccc`). Should I revert `cccccc` or rollback to `bbbbbb`?

Comment: This is for a private git repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do:

```
git checkout -b dev_on_b bbbbbbb
```

which will leave the branch with cccccc alone and give you a new branch starting from bbbbbb.  When you want to return to using ccccc you can do either of:

```
git merge branch_with_cccccc          # bring cccccc into dev_on_b
```

or

```
git checkout branch_with_ccccc
```

Answer (score 8):

Just do

```
git branch for_later
git reset --hard bbbbbb
```

Of course, don't do this if cccccc is already pushed. In that case, use revert.

Comment: Did you mean pushed to github?

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com - Yes, to any central repo shared to others

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution depends on whether this is a public git repository or not.

If you use this command, `git revert HEAD^` then it will revert to (2), which may be the correct thing.

But, you will need to make certain that you revert back to (3) when you do a (4) and then merge in the changes when you commit again.

You may want to look at this, as it will discuss different options, based on different situations:
http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It's actually for a private repo, with a few private contributors.